# typescript missing argument gets auto-assigned

Tags: typescript

I have this function using typescript:

```js
function more(argv: {a: number, b?: string}): number{
    
    console.log( b)
    return a
}
```

and I'm calling it like so:

```js
let arc = more({a: 5})
```

In the console, I get `10`. I expected `undefined` or some error.

Where does the number 10 come from?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you are console logging "b" and returning "a". However, it looks like you mean to be console logging "argv.b" and returning "argv.a". Therefore, I believe what is actually happening is that there is some existing variable "b" defined elsewhere and being logged here. Either way, if you update the variables in the function as I've done, you should get the expected result.

Comment: no, I didn't mean to log `argv.b`, but `b`. I was curious about the value of `b`, i.e. does an optionnal argument that is not provided get assigned a value. But you're right: elsewhere in the program a `let a` and a `let b` are defined.

Comment: My point is: your function doesn't have any arguments named b. It has one named argv, which has properties named 'a' and 'b', but you're not doing anything with that argument, or its properties, in that function.